# How to insert the contents of a JavaScript variable into specific positions in html?

Tags: javascript, html, replace

Given the following code:

```
<head><script>var label = "hello123";</script></head>
<body><h1>**[here]**</h1><p>This is the value: <span>**[here]**</span></body>
```

How can I insert the value of the var label in the indicated positions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select the required elements using `document.querySelector` and assign the variable to it's `textContent` and loop through the selected elements to change its `textContent`.

```js
var label = "hello123";

document.querySelector('h1').textContent = label;

document.querySelector('span').textContent = label;
```

```html
<body><h1></h1><p>This is the value: <span></span></body>
```

-- Edit --

In order to select multiple elements by className use `document.querySelectorAll`.

```js
var label = "hello123";

document.querySelectorAll('.someClass').forEach((ele) => {
    ele.textContent = label;
});
```

```html
<h1 class="someClass"></h1><p>This is the value: <span class="someClass"></span>
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about `textContent`. Should they also put the `<script>` tag at the end of the body? I would guess that if they do this from the `<head>` tag it won't work..

Comment: Placing script in head tag mean you are not waiting for `DOM` to get loaded, so you will get error when you try to access the html elements which are not yet loaded. Therefore, script tags are generally placed before the end of body tag or you can place the script in head tag, but you need to wrap your script code inside event like `DOMContentLoaded` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

Comment: Yes, the original poster's code has their `<script>` tag in the head.

Comment: What about the text should be replaced on a class tag item? like: <body><h1 class="here1"></h1><p>This is the value: <span class="class1"></span></body>

Comment: In that case, select elements by class name `document.querySelector('.here1').textContent = label;` and `document.querySelector('.class1').textContent = label;`

Comment: But, when you have to replace the content of various spans with the same class just replace the first one

Comment: @P00LR0CK - In that case you need to use `document.querySelectorAll` and use loop.

Comment: @randomSoul then, is there anyway to replace multiple spans with the same class? thanks +1 in advance.

Comment: @P00LR0CK - See Edit. Yes. If you want to only target span elements with certain class use `document.querySelectorAll('span.className')` and apply loop to change it's textContent.Ex. If you want to target span which have class "lorem", then use `document.querySelectorAll('span.lorem')`